# Why AWS SQS and SNS policies require "ID" element?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

The AWS documentation just mentions it is required and be unique, but doesn't explain beyond that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_id.html

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why are you asking?

Comment: The most plausible explanation is that the aforementioned AWS services need unique ID's in order to work properly, which is why they are required.  I'm not a member of the AWS teams and I didn't sit in on their requirements stakeholder meetings, so I can't say for sure.  But Amazon SNS is a "subscriber-based" service, so it makes sense that it would require unique ID's (per subscriber).

Comment: Are you encountering a specific problem or limitation related to this? Is the ID requirement impacting you in any way that you need help with?

Comment: None of other resource based policies like the ones for S3 and KMS require this ID element.   Even for SQS and SNS they are allowing duplicate ID values. Just curious why they made this ID element as mandatory in the case of SQS and SNS.